# error in log trigger before delete, i can't find error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Where is the mistake, it seems to me good, but I get the error.

I tried and this referencing old as old new as new.

Maybe the error is in the variables.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger before_delete
      2         before delete
      3     on accounts
      4  declare 
      5     v_username varchar2(20);
      6   begin
      7     select user into v_username
      8     from dual;
      9     insert into accounts_history
     10     (
     11         id, 
     12             new_name,
     13             old_name,
     14             new_amount,
     15             old_amount,
     16             change_date,
     17         delted_by
     18     )
     19     values
     20     (      
     21         :old.acc_id
     22         :old.acc_name
     23         :old.acc_name
     24         :old.acc_amount
     25         :old.acc_amount
     26         sysdate,
     27         v_username
     28   );
     29   end;
     30   /
        insert into accounts_history
            *
    ERROR at line 9:
    ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
```

Answer (score 3):

The error seems fairly clear here - you have a statement level trigger, not a row level trigger (no `for each row` clause), and [you can't use the old/new pseudorecords at statement level](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E).

As it looks like that is actually want you want, you need to add that clause:

```
create or replace trigger before_delete
before delete
on accounts
for each row
begin
    insert into accounts_history
    (
        id,
        new_name,
        old_name,
        new_amount,
        old_amount,
        change_date,
        delted_by
    )
    values
    (
        :old.acc_id,
        :old.acc_name,
        :old.acc_name,
        :old.acc_amount,
        :old.acc_amount,
        sysdate,
        user
   );
end;
/
```

You don't need to query from dual to get the `user` into a variable, you can assign it directly; but you don't need that variable at all; you can refer to `user` call directly in the `values` clause.